# MVVM: Where to Place Methods used by Most ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, methods, replication

I have a few ViewModels which run a process from a simple string parameter. I want them to all use the same method to do it so as to not repeat code.

I was thinking about putting this method in ViewModelBase, however wouldn't that replicate the code anyway?

Comment: Why do you think that would replicate code?

Comment: Purpose of inheritance is to remove code duplication and make derived classes use same method. So `ViewModelBase` seems correct solution in your case

Comment: The simplest is to add the method to the ViewModelBase, then all your views inherit from it. This doesn't duplicate code.

Answer (score 4):

> I was thinking about putting this method in ViewModelBase, however wouldn't that replicate the code anyway?

No. How could defining a method in one single base class lead to code duplication?

If you have a method that may be used by all (or nearly all) of your view models and you also have a common base class that all view models inherit from, defining the common method in the base class sounds like a good idea. This is the main purpose of using a common base class in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

How about you just write a little helper class that contains the method that you want to call?

Comment: One of the ViewModel's benefit (MVVM pattern) is testability. Using static "helper" method will remove possibility to "mock" this method.